# Two cytoscape.js instances spitted with primitive splitter... Can resize in only one direction

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRGSo.png)
The splitter can be moved in only one direction, but if remove the last `var cyR` works just fine

Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Introduction to cytoscape.js</title>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.9.4/cytoscape.min.js'></script>
    
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
            height: 600px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        #cyL {
            width: 50%;
            display: flex;
        }
        
        .splitter {
            background-color: black;
            cursor: ew-resize;
            height: 100%;
            width: 4px;
        }
        
        
        #cyR {
            flex: 1;
            display: flex;
            background-color: gold;
    
        }
    </style>

</head>


<body>

<div class="container">
    <div id="cyL"></div>
    <div id="splitter" class="splitter"></div>
    <div id="cyR"></div>
</div>


<script>
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        
        const splitter = document.getElementById('splitter');
        let L = splitter.previousElementSibling;
        let R = splitter.nextElementSibling;
        
        let x = 0;
        let w = 0;
        
        
        const onMouseDown = function (e) {
            
            L = splitter.previousElementSibling;
            R = splitter.nextElementSibling;
            
            x = e.clientX;
            w = L.getBoundingClientRect().width;
            
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
        };
        
        const onMouseMove = function (e) {
            const dx = e.clientX - x;
            
            const width = ((w + dx) * 100) / splitter.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
            L.style.width = `${width}%`;
            
            splitter.style.cursor = 'col-resize';
            document.body.style.cursor = 'col-resize';
            
            L.style.userSelect = 'none';
            L.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
            
            R.style.userSelect = 'none';
            R.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        };
        
        const onMouseUp = function () {
            splitter.style.removeProperty('cursor');
            document.body.style.removeProperty('cursor');
            
            L.style.removeProperty('user-select');
            L.style.removeProperty('pointer-events');
            
            R.style.removeProperty('user-select');
            R.style.removeProperty('pointer-events');
            
            // Remove the handlers of `mousemove` and `mouseup`
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
        };
        
        splitter.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
    });

    var cyL = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cyL'),
        elements: [
            { data: { id: 'node_1' } },
            { data: { id: 'node_2' } },
            {
                data: {
                    id: 'edge',
                    source: 'node_1',
                    target: 'node_2'
                }
            }]
    });
    
   var cyR = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cyR'),
        elements: [
            { data: { id: 'node_1' } },
            { data: { id: 'node_2' } },
            {
                data: {
                    id: 'edge',
                    source: 'node_1',
                    target: 'node_2'
                }
            }]
    });
    
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Yes, cytoscape.js replace the `div` place holder with its canvas...
Have no idea how to make it work.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Based on found a sample.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- This code is for demonstration purposes only.  You should not hotlink to Github, Rawgit, or files from the Cytoscape.js documentation in your production apps. -->
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        }
        
        #cyL {
            height: 100%;
            width: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            background-color: #FAEDEF;
        }
        
        #splitter {
            height: 100%;
            width: 5px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 0;
            cursor: ew-resize;
            background-color: gold;
        }
        
        #cyR {
            height: 100%;
            width: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 0;
            background-color: #EDF1FA;
            border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
    </style>
    
    <meta charset=utf-8/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
    <title>Multiple instances</title>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.9.4/cytoscape.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cyL"></div>
<div id="cyR"></div>
<div id="splitter"></div>
<script>
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        
        const splitter = document.getElementById('splitter');
        let L, R;
        
        let x = 0;
        let w = 0;
        
        
        const onMouseDown = function (e) {
            
            L = splitter.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling;
            R = splitter.previousElementSibling;
            
            x = e.clientX;
            w = L.getBoundingClientRect().width;
            
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
        };
        
        const onMouseMove = function (e) {
            const dx = x - e.clientX ;
            
            const X = ((w - dx) * 100) / splitter.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
            splitter.style.left = `${X}%`;

            R.style.left = `${X}%`;
            R.style.width = `${100 - X}%`;
    
            L.style.width = `${X}%`;
            
            splitter.style.cursor = 'col-resize';
            document.body.style.cursor = 'col-resize';
            
            L.style.userSelect = 'none';
            L.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
            
            R.style.userSelect = 'none';
            R.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        };
        
        const onMouseUp = function () {
            splitter.style.removeProperty('cursor');
            document.body.style.removeProperty('cursor');
            
            L.style.removeProperty('user-select');
            L.style.removeProperty('pointer-events');
            
            R.style.removeProperty('user-select');
            R.style.removeProperty('pointer-events');
            
            // Remove the handlers of `mousemove` and `mouseup`
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
        };
        
        splitter.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
    });
    var cyL = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cyL'),
        elements: [
            { data: { id: 'node_1' } },
            { data: { id: 'node_2' } },
            {
                data: {
                    id: 'edge',
                    source: 'node_1',
                    target: 'node_2'
                }
            }]
    });

    var cyR = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cyR'),
        elements: [
            { data: { id: 'node_1' } },
            { data: { id: 'node_2' } },
            {
                data: {
                    id: 'edge',
                    source: 'node_1',
                    target: 'node_2'
                }
            }]
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```